# Error Expected a value ot type '(() => void)?', but got one of type '+Future<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to save data to firestore using flutter, the tricky part is my textformfield sets the data as null or "" because it sets the data as the form page loads in and then I get the error : Expected a value ot type '(() => void)?', but got one of type '+Future'

Below is my code:

```
  final barcode = TextEditingController();
  final price = TextEditingController();//these are from my textformfield
  final stock = TextEditingController();
  final color = TextEditingController();

  addData() async {
    // ASYNC HERE
    Map<String, dynamic> theData = {
      "Color": color.text,
      "Price": price.text,
      "Stock": stock.text,
    };
    CollectionReference collectionReference = Firestore.instance.collection("products");
    await collectionReference.doc(barcode.text).set(theData);
  }
```

I think the answer is probably something to do with a future function somewhere.

Below is where I call addData:

```
  FloatingActionButton.extended(
    onPressed: addData(),
    label: Text('Done'),
    icon: Icon(Icons.add),
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
  ),
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the code you shared. It is elsewhere in your code. Perhaps where you are calling `addData()`.

Comment: Have updated the question, hope this helps

Comment: @Randal Schwartz is correct. Remove the parentheses.

Answer (score 6):

You want `onPressed: addData` (no parens) so that you're deferring the invocation of the code until the FAB is pressed.  Instead you're invoking it immediately as you are setting up the FAB.  Ouch.

Comment: Thank you so much, this has been griefing me for a couple of days, and it's just the damn parentheses